# How can I check "source map"/"transpiled javascript" consistency?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor, source-maps

Chrome inspector (and Firefox) does not offer proper debugging :(

1. I'm dealing with fuzzy breakpoints:

[image: Chrome break points]

2. Variables highlights are inconsistent:

[image]

3. Stepping over next function call jumps to random places
4. Formatting js code does not solve the issue

**Does it have anything to do with the source map?**

Looks like it's a *YES*

**I'm using Meteor 1.5 and Chrome 58. I have both the javascript transpiled source and the source map. How can I check that they are consistent?**

I've brutally opened both files and compared them:

- javascript source

  ```
  ./local/build/programs/web.browser/app/app.js
  https://pastebin.com/XEgCzFDd
  ```
- source map

  ```
  ./local/build/programs/web.browser/app/app.js.map
  https://pastebin.com/sMhBfvQg
  ```

Also posted on meteor forums: https://forums.meteor.com/t/incorrect-source-maps/37234

Comment: Yes it has everything to do with transpiling and source map. What options do you use to generate the source map? (Different flavors have different pros/cons). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44481550/6730571) about what happens to `const`, and resulting inconsistencies.

Comment: Comparing the deserialized source maps and the original javascript file, it looks indeed broken

Comment: You can take a look at [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43765806/268093) which I answered a short time ago. There appear to be a number of issues with Meteor source maps (and potentially with the Chrome dev tools in some cases, although I did not come across it). It links to a source map visualizer and the potential issue on GitHub.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau `const` could explain 2. but I'm not in the situation described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44481550/6730571 (very interesting though)

Comment: Yes, not the same situation, but it shows how scoping interferes and trips the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the awesome answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218630/1435156 of @MasterAM, I've managed to downgrade Meteor back to 1.4.3.2 and the debugger is functional again.

See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8611#issuecomment-308388209